# When would pyspark fail with "java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed" from BlockInfo.checkInvariants?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using pyspark and got the following messages:

```
17/12/03 11:57:48 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 1800, 172.31.27.9, executor 0): java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:156)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfo.checkInvariants(BlockInfoManager.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfo.readerCount_$eq(BlockInfoManager.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:367)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:366)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:366)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:361)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:361)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:736)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:342)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

17/12/03 11:57:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage 5.0 (TID 1801, 172.31.27.9, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4871 bytes)
17/12/03 11:57:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 5.0 (TID 1801) on 172.31.27.9, executor 0: java.lang.AssertionError (assertion failed) [duplicate 1]
17/12/03 11:57:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.2 in stage 5.0 (TID 1802, 172.31.27.9, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4871 bytes)
17/12/03 11:57:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 5.0 (TID 1802) on 172.31.27.9, executor 0: java.lang.AssertionError (assertion failed) [duplicate 2]
17/12/03 11:57:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 1803, 172.31.27.9, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4871 bytes)
17/12/03 11:57:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 1803) on     172.31.27.9, executor 0: java.lang.AssertionError (assertion failed) [duplicate 3]
17/12/03 11:57:48 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
17/12/03 11:57:48 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 5.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/12/03 11:57:48 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 5
17/12/03 11:57:48 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 5 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:446) failed in 0.078 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 1803, 172.31.27.9, executor 0): java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:156)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfo.checkInvariants(BlockInfoManager.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfo.readerCount_$eq(BlockInfoManager.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:367)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:366)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:366)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:361)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:361)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:736)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:342)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It seems it happened to others `TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times; aborting job`, but I am particularly concerned the messages: `... Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 1803, 172.31.27.9, executor 0): java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed`.

I doubt the problem happens when writing to RDD, there may be errors on write-in, and Spark has trouble to parse later.
I am using `ALS` library and the `Rating` object. So before save to RDD it is more convenient for me to map RDD to

```
data.map(lambda x: (x.user, x.product, x.rating)).saveAsTextFile ("hdfs://"+master_ip+":9000/RDD/data")
```

and read and parse as

```
data = sc.textFile("hdfs://"+master_ip+":9000/RDD/data")
data = data.map(lambda x: x[1:-1]).map(lambda x: x.split(", ")).\
              map(lambda x: Rating(int(x[0]), int(x[1]), float(x[2])))
```

I am pretty curious since these error messages didn't appear every time and are not reproducible always.
   I am using spark 2.2.0 and hapdoop 2.7. Did anyone see this before?

Thanks!

Comment: Given it's an invariant that should not have happened. Is this reproducible? Mind sharing the query? What's the master URL / cluster manager?

Comment: @Jacek No, it is not always reproducible! I have added part of codes in my question. I doubt some possible reasons, but still testing. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any other errors before the error in question? It appears as executors could have got killed by YARN (perhaps due to memory constraints?)

Comment: None. Everything's goes well except the messages. Now I am testing. I rewrote the RDD and do reading again. It seems I didn't have such problem. I used t2.xlarge for 16GB each instance at AWS. Memory should not be the issue.

Comment: I will say, the problem is NOT gone. But the frequency becomes less.

Comment: Thanks! It is auto correction. My code of course indicates `hdfs`. Now the frequency became I run 10-15 times it happened once.

Comment: @Jacek, now I found error messages (written in files) are `....
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 1803, xxxx, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages`. Is the YARN problem?

Comment: Edit your question and include the stacktrace there. Thanks.